# Linux shutdown permission

Tags: linux, permissions

Suppose you install a desktop environment, say ubuntu or debian. You can shutdown the system by clicking a button somewhere on your system menu as a normal user. You don't need to switch to superuser to accomplish that.

However in the same desktop environment, if I open a terminal (say gnome-terminal) as a normal user, and type

```
shutdown -h now
```

I would be prompted by

```
shutdown: need to be root
```

The only way to shutdown is to prepend the command with a sudo.

Can anyone explain why this is so?

Thanks
KC

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18503/how-does-the-power-button-shut-the-computer-down-without-root-permission

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question asked by K.Chen is: why do I need sudo privileges when I do it from CLI, ahile I do not need such privileges when I do it from the GUI.

The first part of the answer is that people who design Desktop Environments, like Gnome, KDE, Xfce, Mate, Cinnamon, ... try to simplify the work of their users, and they configure shutting down and rebooting without requiring sudo credentials. This, incidentally, implies that there must be a shutdown sequence which does **not** involve the program shutdown, which does require sudo privileges (no way around that).

I do not know in detail how each DE does it, but I know that there is a gentle way to bring down, or restart/shutdown/hibernate your system, which does not require root privileges. You can find the original post [in an Arch Linux Forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127962). In essence, it amounts to issuing hese commands:

halt

```
 #!/bin/bash
 dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit"/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

reboot

```
 #!/bin/bash
 dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit"  /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
```

dbus-suspend

```
 #!/bin/bash
 dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

hibernate

```
 #!/bin/bash
 dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate
```

My guess is that the GUI buttons use roughly these commands. To be certain one should look into the code, but I believe this is a safe bet.

Comment: If someone remote login to a machine that also has a desktop environment running, can he or she issue these commands and succesfully shutdown/reboot/suspend/hibernate?

Comment: There's a malicious side to this question, I believe some discretion should be exercised.

Comment: Why malicious?  If it can be abused, sysops should know and then know how to protect against it.

Comment: I am not saying you are being malicious, but that a malicious use could be made of this info. I am already regretting having shared it... Perhaps I should have done like @Matteo

Answer (score 5):

The reason behind this design decision is not technical (you could have a non privileged `shutdown` command or a require a password in the GUI).

- When using a desktop environment the user is *supposed* to have physical access to the machine. Then better to allow a clean shutdown than to let the user push the power button or unplug the power cord.
- When using a shell the user could be a remote user and to avoid a remote shutdown more privileges are requested.

These are not **rules** but just **defaults** based on assumptions: you can have a local user in a shell and a remote user with a desktop environment. If you want to choose the default behavior you can configure your system accordingly.

Comment: I see your point, @Matteo. But like MariusMatutiae said, under the hood DE must have called some program other than "shutdown" to shutdown without superuser privilege. You have any clue what that is?

Answer (score 1):

Sudo (superuser do) allows a system administrator to give certain users (or groups of users) the ability to run some (or all) commands as root while logging all commands and arguments.
shutdown -h command or init 0 command can be used to turn off the machine. But both commands required root privilege to execute.

The command which locates in /sbin must have root privilege to execute it. For finding the location of shutdown command,

type **which shutdown** in terminal.

Hope now your doubt is clear :)

Answer (score -1):

As root you could try setting the sticky bit permission on the shutdown command like this:

```
chmod u+s /sbin/shutdown
```

Once done you should be able to shutdown as a normal user that has permissions to:

```
/sbin/shutdown
```