# shutdown vs shutdown now - shutting down system as non-root

Tags: linux, shutdown, arch-linux

I just observed something strange.

Logged into an archlinux system as a non-privileged user, I executed `shutdown`. As expected, it returned `Must be root.`

To my surprise, executing `shutdown now` it (apparently!) does **not** check if the current user has root privileges. It simply shuts down the machine.

I tried reproduced this both in a tty and a terminal in the Plasma DE.

[Screen recording of the tty](https://imgrush.com/uvPwkGjTPkUG.mp4)

---

I'm running Archlinux with an 4.2.2 Kernel with current packages.

I don't think this is related with [GUI policies](https://superuser.com/questions/666687/linux-shutdown-permission).

tl;dr: shutting down system as non-root with `shutdown now`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not actually my answer –
just reposting an answer that, sadly, has been deleted for unknown reasons.

Source: http://web.archive.org/web/20151014220049/https://superuser.com/questions/985661/shutdown-vs-shutdown-now-shutting-down-system-as-non-root

---

In Arch Linux, under certain circumstances, you may very well shutdown/reboot/hibernate... your pc without root privileges.

[The Arch Linux Wiki page on Power Management under Systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Power_management) states:

> polkit is necessary for power management as an unprivileged user. If you are in a local systemd-logind user session and no other session is active, the following commands will work without root privileges:
>
> systemctl poweroff
>
> systemctl reboot
>
> systemctl suspend
>
> systemctl hibernate

To check whether you are allowed to do this (*i.e.*, you have polkit installed, and your session is not broken) you can use the following command:

```
$  loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID --property=Active
   Active=yes
```

On other `systemd` systems, like my Debian 8, this is not possible despite having the same reply to this command:

```
$  loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID --property=Active
   Active=yes
$ systemctl reboot
 ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.login1.reboot ===
 Authentication is required for rebooting the system.
 Authenticating as: ,,, (myusername)
 Password:
```

which indicates that `polkit` has been set up by default in different ways on Arch Linux and Debian. The Arch Linux people see an advantage of this over `sudo`, in that they state, in [the wiki page on Polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit):

> Polkit is used for controlling system-wide privileges. It provides an organized way for non-privileged processes to communicate with privileged ones. In contrast to systems such as sudo, it does not grant root permission to an entire process, but rather allows a finer level of control of centralized system policy.

As usual, YMMV.

As for `shutdown now`, my guess is that it is a redirection to `systemctl poweroff`, which is allowed to a non-privileged user.

-- https://superuser.com/users/255732/mariusmatutiae